# Open Forms In Normal State

Tags: c#

I have a Mdi form. when I open a form in it in maximize state, after that every form will open in maximize state, and it's not OK for me.
actually the second one must open in normal state
what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can not have both maximized and normal state of forms in MDI window. If you have any form maximized in MDI windows, all other form in MDI window which will be actived will be automaticaly changed to maximized state. It works same way with normal state.
However you can have both minimized state and normal state forms in MDI window.

This is standard behaviour of MDI windows. If you want other behaviour, you should consider if is this request realy required and/or you can implement the functionality with other way. For example: create form with no MDI parent but with MDI form as "Owner", the will be form displayed allways on top of MDI form.